# ambiguous use of init with default values

Tags: swift

I have class that have two similar looking initializers:

```
public init(
        contentInsets: MyInsets = .init(vertical: .level0, horizontal: .level6),
        midToLeftSpacing: CGFloat = 0,
        rightToMidSpacing: CGFloat = 0
)

public init(
        contentInsets: MyInsets = .init(vertical: .level0, horizontal: .level6),
        midToLeftSpacing: MyInsetLevel = .level0,
        rightToMidSpacing: MyInsetLevel = .level0
)
```

Now i run into problem, looks like when i trying to call initializer compiler can't figure out which one to chose:

```
init(
vertical: .level0,
left: .level22,
right: .level0
)
```

Gives error - `Ambiguous use of 'init'`

It could be easily fixed with modifying initializer or adding next argument with default value, but it doesn't look right, is there any other way to specify init method called?

Comment: "is there any other way to specify init method called?" You have two inits with identical signatures. So, no. Not without subclassing. But you could write factory static methods instead of an overloaded init (to me, that's beautifully clean).

Comment: You can create a class with two initializers with the same property names but differing types. Can you post all of the relevant code so that we can reproduce it? Also unclear if this is your class or an extension of an existing one.

Comment: @matt the signatures aren't identical, they're just ambiguous in this particular context.

Comment: Well, you have not given enough information for me to know whether that's true or not, have you?

Comment: @matt i didnt copy code from project,  but i thought question is clear, i used solution provided by Rob answer, though it's rather "ugly" way to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't match your code (there is no `init(vertical:left:right)` defined), so I'm going to try to generalize this problem a bit with a full example that avoids the extra types. I'll just use Double and Int here.

Imagine a struct `X` that internally stores three Doubles:

```
struct X {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
    var z: Double
    init(x: Double = 0, y: Double = 0, z: Double = 0) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    }
}
```

You also want to be able to pass three Ints instead, but all three must either be Doubles or Ints, and you want default values. **Every use of default values is just a shorthand for an extra method with fewer parameters.** To avoid conflicts, you need to include at least one of the parameters as non-default:

```
extension X {
    init(x: Int, y: Int = 0, z: Int = 0) {
        self.init(x: Double(x), y: Double(y), z: Double(z))
    }
    init(y: Int, z: Int = 0) { self.init(x: 0, y: y, z: z) }
    init(z: Int) { self.init(x: 0, y: 0, z: z) }
}
```

Now, every combination is legal, but there are no ambiguities.

This is nice when there's just one extra way to call the init. But maybe you want there to be many. Then a protocol is useful. For example, this approach allows either Int or Double for every parameter:

```
protocol XParameter {
    var xParameterValue: Double { get }
}

extension Double: XParameter {
    var xParameterValue: Double { self }
}

extension Int: XParameter {
    var xParameterValue: Double { Double(self) }
}

struct X {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
    var z: Double
    init(x: some XParameter = 0, y: some XParameter = 0, z: some XParameter = 0) {
        self.x = x.xParameterValue
        self.y = y.xParameterValue
        self.z = z.xParameterValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  i solved it the same way though it forced me to remove default values from second initializer, which's not convenient